# What is meaning of symbol "!" in python?

Tags: python

In my code that I was working on, my teacher used symbol !. Can anyone tell what is meaning of symbol ! in this code?

```
n! = (n-1)! * n
sum(n) = sum(n-1) + n
```

Comment: That's not valid Python. They mean for it to represent the "factorial" function though.

Comment: Okay so you mean that ! is nothing in python. Right?

Comment: That's factorial, for instance `x! = x * (x-1) * (x-2) * .........1`

Comment: There is at least one place that `!` is used in Python syntax, but it has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: ! can be used in combination with = to be !=, which means not equal. But in your example ! is irrelevant if translated directly to python.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually ran the code you would have seen there is a syntax error:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> n! = (n-1)! * n
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    n! = (n-1)! * n
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You cannot have a `!` in a variable name.

This snippet is most probably pseudo-code with factorials for practicing recursion or something like that.